# Constructing a Hubbard-Stratonovich Transform that goes from a theory of Electrostatics to a theory like Magnetostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, duality

I'm talking about a completely classical theory.
Suppose I start with 
$$H = \int(\nabla \phi)^2 $$
I am talking about calculation of the partition function here
$$Z = \int D[\phi] e^{(-\beta\int(\nabla \phi)^2 )} $$
We can introduce a vector H-S field $\vec\psi$ such that the new Hamiltonian becomes (including $\beta$) (up to some factors)
$$ H = \int\frac{(\vec\psi)^2}{\beta}-i\vec\psi\cdot\nabla\phi $$
which you have to integrate over $\vec\psi$ and $\phi$ to get $Z$.
Doing an integration by parts on the second term and then integrating over psi, we get the constraint from the functional delta function $\delta(\nabla\cdot\vec\psi) = 0$ that 
$$\nabla\cdot\vec\psi = 0$$
with the new Hamiltonian
$$ H = \int\frac{(\vec\psi)^2}{\beta} $$
Because of the constraint we write $\vec\psi = \nabla \times \vec A$ and we change the integration variable to $\vec A$ (and ignore the Jacobian since we're calculating $Z$). Thus, we get
$$Z = \int D[\vec A] e^{(-\int\frac{(\nabla \times A)^2}{\beta} )} $$
Which is the form for magnetostatics (without currents). Therefore we conclude elecrostatics without charges is dual to magnetostatics without currents.

But I dont understand how to show this duality when there are charges involved in the original electrostatics theory. Here,
$$H = \int(\nabla \phi)^2 + \rho\phi $$
Hubbard-Stratonovichizing, we get
$$ H = \int\frac{(\vec\psi)^2}{\beta}-i\vec\psi\cdot\nabla\phi + \rho\phi $$
I'm guessing we should get the constraint $\nabla\cdot\vec\psi = \rho$ here but the lack of an $i$ in the coupling term is messing things up. What do I do here? What am I doing wrong? Also, I don't understand how to proceed once this  clears up. I'm guessing we have to take a singular part and a smooth part separately and do it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but maybe you should try the real stratonovich transformation ( without the i).